# Django: connect social media local user but disallow login using social media credentials

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth, python-social-auth

Problem:

My Django webapp allows users to login using email/password. Now I need to connect their one or more social accounts to the existing account but only for the purpose of accessing their social media content. They will not be able to login in to my webapp using their social credentials. They still have to use the existing email/password to login in to my webapp.

Work so far:

I have looked at django-allauth and python-social-auth but not sure if I can be selective about not allowing login but still connect the social accounts.

Question:

So is it possible to achieve this using django-allauth or python-social-auth ? Is there a simpler method ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`python-social-auth` let's you do that by disabling the step that creates the user in the pipeline ([pipeline docs here](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html)), you can even define an early step in that pipeline that enforces that `request.user` is authenticated.

Another option to consider, is include the views in your `urls.py` but wrap then in a `login_required()` decorator, ensuring that only authed user can use this association mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. Does it also allow to attach same social account to multiple existing users ?

Comment: No, one social to multiple is not supported, but might be possible to enforce that in the pipeline, multiple social to one user yes.